# How to alternate between two scenes in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, scene

I'm creating a game using Cocos2d-x. I'm currently creating a gameover menu, in that menu I need to be able to switch to both my menuscene and my gamescene (When I say switch to gamescene I only really only mean "to restart" the game). But circular dependencies stop me from being able to do this.
MenuScene needs to be able to use`GameScene::create()` in order to switch to the gamescene and the gameover menu needs to be able to use both of `GameScene::create() or its restart funtion` and `MenuScene::create()` which is giving me circular dependency problems
I can't separate my gameover menu to it's own file as I still need the GameScene dependency and  GameScene would need gameover.
I can't combine them as GameScene then needs to depend on MenuScene

So my question is: How do I alternate between two scenes in cocos2d-x c++.

I read somewhere about pushing and popnig scenes in Director, but I don't really understand how that works, or if I could use that for my purpose.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Now that I think about it, could I not just push mMenuScene to Director before switching to GameScene? That should work if I understand that push/pop mechanic correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a misconception of how complex this is, using the way I provided below you **can and should** definitely split your game over scene into its own file.

The scene replace is easy enough, just use the code below:

**Including your file:**

```
#include "MainGameScene.h"
```

**Creating and switching scenes in your onClickListener:**

```
auto gameOverScene = GameOverScene::createScene();

// use code below for hard replace
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(gameOverScene );

// or use code below for transition fade replace
Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(1, gameOverScene , Color3B(255, 255, 255)));
```

As for the restart functionality. I usually provide a callback to my game over scene that I call when the restart button has been clicked. Not that I ever swap out my scene completely for a mobile game over scene, but I still do it the same way regardless. So lets do steps (This assumes you seperated your game over scene into it's own file named GameOverScene :) ).

1. Store a function pointer in your GameOverScene.h to your reset method in MainGameScene:

   ```
   std::function<void()> _resetCallback;
   ```
2. Set your function pointer from the main game scene, before running with the GameOverScene.

   ```
   auto gameOverScene = GameOverScene::createGameOverScene();
   gameOverScene->setResetCallback(std::bind(&MainGameScene::reset, this));
   ```
3. When your reset button is clicked, call the _resetCallback

   ```
   void GameOverScene::onResetClicked(Ref* sender)
   {
     _resetCallback();
   }
   ```

This should provide you with all the functionality you need to set up a what you want as well as remove the circular dependency that you have. I have used this way many times before and it always works. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: How would this work if I want to be able to switch between the Menu- and Game-scene?  Do you mean that I combine them into one scene/layer? (Now that I think about it, that might not be such a bad idea)  Otherwise I have another way in mind which uses function pointers, which you so kindly reminded me existed :)

Comment: In my opinion the scene files should always be separate files. It would be exactly the same. The menu has to include the header file to you GameScene.h, so and you'll use the exact same code I laid out above to swap between the scene. I don't see why that would be different to Game->GameOver. If they're all separate you can just navigate to either one from any other one. You should NOT combine your scene's into one. It's a very bad idea in overall design and general game development. It will make maintenance and bug fixes very difficult.